# AVG of SUM in SQL

Tags: sql

Here's my code:

```
SELECT B1_COD, SB1030.B1_DESC, B2_CM1, B2_QATU, SUM (B2_QATU)
FROM SB1030 
INNER JOIN SB2030 ON B1_COD = B2_COD
WHERE (B1_TIPO='PA') AND (B2_QATU <> '0')
```

I'd like to:

- multiply `b2_cm1` by `b2_qatu` creating `b2_VAL`
- sum all `b2_qatu` with same `b1_cod` creating `b2_SAL`
- divide `b2_VAL` by `b2_SAL`

Could anyone help me?????

Thanks

Comment: What Excel have to do with it?

Comment: Your request is not precise. You want b2_sal per b1_cod. So your result records are one record per b1_cod. (That is a GROUP BY Expression by the way.) Do you want the b2_val that you need for the final division calculated also per b1_cod or as a total over all records?

Comment: Can you specify which SQL you are using (e.g. MSSQL, MySQL etc?)

Comment: @PankajJaju it´s a query within Excel

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . I tried using GROUP BY but I got an error saying it's invalid since it's not cotained in an agregating function. I dont know what it means. I don't need the final result calculated as a total of all records.

Comment: @TomasPastircak using SQL within Microsft Query in Office 2010

Comment: The error means every column must either be in the GROUP BY clause or be aggregated (with SUM, COUNT and the like). As to my question: The final result will be per b1_cod. b2_sal, the divident, is also based on values only for the particular b1_cod. So: Is the b2_val, the divisor, built per b1_code, too, or is it calculated over all records?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner
I dont know if I got what you said, but the final result should be: the dividend of the b2_val per b2_sal for each b1_cod. Ie:

B1_Cod B1_QATU B1_CM1
00054 200  2
00054 300  3
00077 100  1
00077 400  0.5

I would expect to get the following:
B1_Cod B1_Sal  B1_Val B1_new_field
00054 500  1300 0.38
00077 500  300 1.66

Is it clear or too confusig?

Comment: That is easy to understand. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you are looking for. A list of b1_cods with sums and a calculation based on the sums.

```
select 
  b1_cod, 
  sb1030.b1_desc, 
  sum(b2_cm1) as sum_cm1, 
  sum(b2_qatu) as b2_sal, 
  sum(b2_qatu * b2_cm1) as b2_val,
  sum(b2_qatu) / sum(b2_qatu * b2_cm1) as new_field
from sb1030 
inner join sb2030 on b1_cod = b2_cod
where b1_tipo = 'pa' and b2_qatu <> '0'
group by b1_cod, sb1030.b1_desc
order by b1_cod, sb1030.b1_desc;
```

Comment: I don´t know why, but it says "coudnt add table sb0130" although I can connect with it in other queries... any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want the result b2_VAL and b2_SAL?

Try using WITH CTE:

```
 WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT SUM(B1_COD) AS B1_COD, SB1030.B1_DESC,B2_CM1*B2_QATU AS b2_VAL, SUM (B2_QATU) AS  B2_QATU
 FROM SB1030 
 INNER JOIN SB2030 ON B1_COD = B2_COD
 WHERE (B1_TIPO='PA') AND (B2_QATU <> '0'))
 SELECT B1_COD+B2_QATU, b2_VAL
 FROM CTE
```

Is it something like that you are looking for?

Comment: it says that the data is VARCHAR, so it invalid for operator SUM. It says besides that no column name was specified for column 1 of CTE